# Getting a List of Artisan Commands Programmatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When you're using the Laravel PHP Framework, is there a way, (at runtime), to programmatically fetch a list of currently configured and available `artisan` commands?  I'm basically looking for way to know

1. All the command names
2. The class or objects that corresponds to that class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, self help desk strikes as soon as I ask myself the question clearly.

```
//app()->make('artisan')->all();        
foreach(Artisan::all() as $key=>$command)
{
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump(get_class($command));
}
```

Comment: The helpful rubber duck strikes again! I expect you could also parse the help from the `artisan` command, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: How can we retrieve additional information about an Artisan command, such as the input parameters that a command accepts?