# Get artisan command signature programmatically

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to get some info of my custom command in Laravel from my controller, but I don't know which method to get command signature or other info of command. Actually I have a select box with a command list, when choosing an option, my code in back-end will run and return selected command info, then display on textarea.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279294/getting-a-list-of-artisan-commands-programmatically). 
I also google laravel source but couldn't find where artisan method source placed.

```php
foreach(Artisan::all() as $key=>$command)
{
 echo $command->getDescription(); // show description
 echo $command->getName(); // show name
 echo $command->getSignature(); // error because this method doesn't exist.
}
```

1. Is there any method to get command signature or other info?
2. Where can I find artisan command method source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you are correct, Laravel commands do not offer a getter for signatures. As an alternative you could look into the following workarounds.

1. You can use the `$name` as signature.

```
protected $name = 'app:do:something';
```

I'm not sure if this is  a common (or best) practice, but it seems to do the trick.

2. If that doesn't cut it for you, you can implement and extend your own `CommandWithSignature` (or `SignatureAwareTrait`) which exposes a `getSignature()` method.

```
public class CommandWithSignature {
    protected $signature;

    public function getSignature(): string
    {
        return $this->signature;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used the trait approach and works fine, thanks!